# How are make components reusable when using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

When using redux, we move the logic out of the component. Component is only the presentation layer. If one has to share the component across projects or publish it for the world to use, it will not be of much use as the component will have only the presentation layer. This becomes more prominent when the component has many internal state variables and actions, which are do not effect the rest of the application for ex a date picker component. A date picker has many actions like change month, next month, prev month, change year, open picker, close picker etc and internal state variables like selected month, selected year, selected day etc. By using the redux philosophy these state variables and operations will lie outside the component in  global store and reducers. Such a component will be very difficult to share with other projects. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Put in some code to better explain your problem

Comment: Redux **does not require** you to entirely avoid internal state and internal logic.

Comment: @zerkms I struggle a lot with this too and I do use internal states and internal logic. If I wanna keep the form data from a modal box when I temporarily close it for instance, I d need to use a global state, which makes the form less reusable.

Comment: @Pankaj did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Presentational components can have own state, there is nothing wrong while it is UI state rather than data. For instance, datepicker should receive currently selected date and action callbacks with props, while keep currently displayed month in state.

Comment: You mean a nested component can at the same time be a container component which can then be reused insider another container?